# Calling a Unity WebGl Function from JavaScript (Vue)

Tags: unity-game-engine, vue.js, unity-webgl

I have a VueJs Project right now, where I'm building a web page. In order to show 3D Content and let the User work with it, I wanted to embed a Unity Project as WebGL. I´m not a professional programmer, my knowledge is more selfe-taught from what I can find at the Internet.

First of all I created a plugin, as it is explained [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html?_ga=2.244155911.384034017.1572118121-511052720.1571482865). My .jslib file looks like that:

```
var UnityJavascipt = {

 $JustAWebGLObject:
  {
  },
  SendToJavscript: function ()
  {
              console.log("worked!")
  }     
}; autoAddDeps(UnityJavascipt , '$JustAWebGLObject'); mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, UnityJavascipt );
```

I embed my Unity WebGl like that in Vue:

```
<template>
  <unity src="static/Build/game.json" width="1000" height="600" unityLoader="static/Build/UnityLoader.js" ref="myInstance"></unity>  
</template>
```

I can also call "SendToJavaScript" from my C# Script. But now it starts to get unclear for me, since I want to be able to call my "SendToJavaScript" Function (or any other one that will be added later) from a outside JavaScript. In the manual they refer to the [emscripten page](http://var+unityjavascipt+%3D+%7B+++++//+This+object+can+hold+variables+for+you.+++++$JustAWebGLObject:+++++%7B++++++++%7D,++++++SendToJavscript:+function+%28%29+++++%7B+++++++++++console.log%28worked!%29+++++%7D++++%7D;+autoAddDeps%28UnityJavascipt+,+'$JustAWebGLObject'%29;+mergeInto%28LibraryManager.library,+UnityJavascipt+%29;)for more detailed information. But for me that all is just very confusing. I already tried to call my function like that in VueJs:

```
_SendToJavaScript()
```

But I always get a ReferenceError: _SendToJavaScript is not defined I also read in the forum here, that it would be possible to call the function like that:

```
UnityInstance.Module.asmLibraryArg._SendToJavaScript()
```

UnityInstance is the Variable from my index.html file, where UnityLoader get's instantiated. But again I'm getting a Reference Error.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong... Communication between WebGL and Vue are essential for my project but I´m stuck here for days. So thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `unityInstance.SendMessage()` [documented here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)

You can pass a callback or call a `.jslib` defined function at the end of your C# method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But SendMessage has no return Value as far as I know. And I would definitely need one... My Aim is to get Data from Unity Webgl to Vuejs